# Source for accurate block timestamps?

Tags: block, timestamp, historical-trade-data

Is there a source of historical data which assigns a relatively consistent and accurate timestamp to each block? This might take the form of a server having precisely logged when they first heard about each block header. Bonus points if extinct blocks are included.

Comment: You probably should state about which period of time you care as more bitcoin-related services emerged as bitcoin gained popularity and what you're asking for requires the existence of a service back in the period of time you care about.